# error with XML syntax - Uncaught exception 'Exception'

Tags: xml, exception

i need to some helps to understand and possibly to solve problem with a php file, this file is part of old whmsonic template that isn't available more to download, i have a fresh installation but there's not solution even with it.

This is the file

```html
<?php
include("language/en.php");
include('config_radio.php');

$ctx = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'timeout' => 10
        )
    )
);

    @ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.10) Gecko/2009042316 WHMSonic/2.0.1');
 $d = @file_get_contents("http://".$GLOBALS['scip'] . ":" . $GLOBALS['scport'] . "/admin.cgi?mode=viewxml&pass=" . $GLOBALS['scpass'], 10, $GLOBALS['ctx']);
    if (!$d) {
       echo "<font color=66CCFF><b>$GLOBALS[lang9]<br>$GLOBALS[lang8]</b></font>"; exit; } else {

  $shoutcast_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($d);
  $bitrate = utf8_decode($shoutcast_xml->BITRATE);
  $streamstatus = utf8_decode($shoutcast_xml->STREAMSTATUS);
  $currentlisteners = utf8_decode($shoutcast_xml->CURRENTLISTENERS);
  $servertitle = utf8_decode($shoutcast_xml->SERVERTITLE);
  $songtitle = utf8_decode($shoutcast_xml->SONGTITLE);
?>
<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="25; URL=stats.php">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="template/style2.css">
</head>

<body style="margin:0px;">
<div align="center">
  <?php if($streamstatus == "1"){ echo ""; } else { echo "<font color=66CCFF><b>$GLOBALS[lang7]<br>$GLOBALS[lang8]</b></font>"; exit;} ?>
  <br>
</div>
<table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%">
      <div align="right"><b><font color="#999999"><?php echo $GLOBALS['lang3'];?>:</font></b></div>
    </td>
    <td width="75%">
      <?php echo "<font color=FFFFFF><b>$GLOBALS[servertitle]</b></font>"; ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%">
      <div align="right"><b><font color="#999999"><?php echo$GLOBALS['servertitle'];?>:</font></b>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td width="75%">
      <?php echo "<font color=FFFFFF><b>$GLOBALS[songtitle]</b></font>"; ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%">
      <div align="right"><b><font color="#999999"><?php echo$GLOBALS['lang5'];?>:</font></b></div>
    </td>
    <td width="75%">
      <?php echo "<font color=FFFFFF><b>$GLOBALS[bitrate] KBPS</b></font>"; ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%">
      <div align="right"><b><font color="#999999"><?php echo$GLOBALS['lang6'];?>:</font></b><font color="#999999"></font>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td width="75%">
      <?php echo "<font color=FFFFFF><b>$GLOBALS[currentlisteners]</b></font>"; ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

ant it is the error that i have in the log

```html
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /home/radionet/public_html/stats.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 /home/radionet/public_html/stats.php(17): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('<?xml version="...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/radionet/public_html/stats.php on line 17
```

line 17 would be

```
       echo "<font color=66CCFF><b>$GLOBALS[lang9]<br>$GLOBALS[lang8]</b></font>"; exit; } else {
```

i ask you some suggestions to solve it, i have tried something alredy following guides for XML syntax files, without solution.

Thank you so much,
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the quotes in the vars`$GLOBALS[]`

Try this:

```
echo "<font color=66CCFF><b>$GLOBALS['lang9']<br>$GLOBALS['lang8']</b></font>"; exit; } else {
```